# How do I filter a column for a given string length in SQLAlchemy ORM?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, string-length

**Edit: Resolved**

I'm trying to implement a rather simple SQL query that returns only the rows that contain strings (Text type in SQLite3) that are less than 17 characters long. This is the query in plan SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE length(col) < 17
```

I tried getting that by using the following statement:

```
result = session.query(Table).filter(func.length(Table.col) < 17).all()
```

SQLAlchemy translates it correctly to
`[SQL: SELECT table.col AS table_col FROM table WHERE length(?) < ?]`
The problem arises with the values it's inserting for the question marks. Namely it replaces the second ? with 17 just fine but the Table.column isn't fetching the actual length, but the object representing that column.
`[parameters: (<property object at 0x00000226998E3590>, 17)]`. This leads to me getting the error
`sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.`.
So how do I properly filter for string length with SQLAlchemy ORM?

Comment: isn't `column` a reserved word? try using a different name for your column?

Comment: Possibly. This isn't the actual statement, I simplified and change some names, so the original name wasn't column. I can edit it in the original question to avoid further confusion.

Comment: I guess the column in your model is not actually a SQLAlchemy column, but a python property, which you can't use in your queries. You could instead probably use a sqlalchemy hybrid property. Note I'm just guessing here, as you haven't posted your model

Comment: It is an actual SQLAlchemy column but I made the (stupid) mistake of using the actual column name rather than the alias that I defined for it in the table class. I'm just surprised that SQLAlchemy gave me the error message it did. I would have expected something more along the lines of "unknown column" in the way of an error message. Still thanks for your reply as it gave me a pointer in the right direction.
I'm not quite sure how to deal with this question now though, since the whole premise of the error was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the mistake was all mine and I simply used the wrong column name as argument for func.length. E.g. this is what the model looked like

```
class Table(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}
    aliased_col = Column('col', Text, nullable=False)
```

and I was trying to query like this

```
result = session.query(Table).filter(func.length(Table.col) < 17).all()
```

when obviously I should have been doing this

```
result = session.query(Table).filter(func.length(Table.aliased_col) < 17).all()
```

which worked perfectly fine. I let myself be confused because the error message pointed me to the property `<property object at 0x00000226998E3590>` which looked plausible at first glance.